# How to create a job post by email parsing?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, email, parse

I want to develop a job board in wordpress in which job posts will be created from email parsing automatically.

With zapier or Postie plugins we can create only blog posts by email parsing.

How to create a job post by email parsing? Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems doable thanks to Postie [image]

Comment: postie is not working for me.